# Некорректно работает ProgressBar

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, нейронные-сети, qt-designer

Написал, что-то вроде нейрона, который учится, в моем случае переводить километры в мили. 
Написал для него набросок интерфейса и столкнулся с проблемой, что неправильно работает `progressBar`, то есть он просто очень быстро доходит до 100, но при этом нейрон еще не обучился.

Для обучения необходим цикл `while` и из-за него скорее всего не работает `progressBar`, ибо в цикле `for`, он знает где ему остановится.

Знаю, что трудно разобраться в моем этом бреду. Но прошу знающих людей помочь. Нужно чтобы он останавливался по завершению обучения нейрона.

**mydesign.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        MainWindow.resize(795, 508)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(230)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(200)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 12))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar1 = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar1.setEnabled(True)
        self.progressBar1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 411, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(14)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.progressBar1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.progressBar1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.progressBar1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 212, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 212, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.progressBar1.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Franklin Gothic Medium")
        self.progressBar1.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar1.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.progressBar1.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.progressBar1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.progressBar1.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.progressBar1.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.progressBar1.setAccessibleName("")
        self.progressBar1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127); border-radius: 10px")
        self.progressBar1.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar1.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar1.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar1.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.progressBar1.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.BottomToTop)
        self.progressBar1.setObjectName("progressBar1")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 90, 491, 301))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 50px")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setLineWidth(0)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 211, 51))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setIndent(85)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 131, 51))
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 25px")
        self.btn1.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn1.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btn1.setDefault(False)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.progressBar1.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 795, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.progressBar1.setFormat(_translate("MainWindow", "%p%"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Клик"))
        self.btn1.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Backspace"))
```

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

"""сам нейрон"""

class Neuron():
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 0.01
        self.last_error = 1.1
        self.smoothing = 0.00001

    def get_last_error(self):
        return self.last_error

    def get_smoothing(self):
        return self.smoothing

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.weight

    def process_input_data(self, input_data):
        return input_data * self.weight

    def train(self, input, expectedResult):
        result_now = input * self.weight

        self.last_error = expectedResult - result_now
        correction = self.last_error / result_now
        correction = correction * self.smoothing

        self.weight += correction


    def check_training(self):
        if(self.last_error > self.smoothing or self.last_error < -self.smoothing):
            return True
        else:
            return False


"""Дизайн для нейрона"""
class mydesign(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Neuron):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mydesign, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        
        self.ui.progressBar1

        self.ui.progressBar1.setMinimum(0)
        self.ui.progressBar1.setMaximum(100)

        """Код, что бы убрать рамки виндовса"""
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        """Кнопка"""
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(0))
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.run)


    def run(self):
        neuron = Neuron() 

        input_data = 10
        expectedResult = 6.21

        self.ui.label.setText("Проходит обучение нейрона")
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()

        iteration = 1

        """Цикл обучения нейрона"""
        while neuron.check_training():
            neuron.train(input_data, expectedResult)
            iteration += 1
            self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(iteration)

        print("Конец")
        print(neuron.get_weight())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    application = mydesign()
    application.show()
 
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать цикл **`while(True)`** в основном потоке - это замораживает интерфейс.

Ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        MainWindow.resize(795, 508)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(230)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(200)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 12))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar1 = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar1.setEnabled(True)
        self.progressBar1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 411, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(14)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.progressBar1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.progressBar1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.progressBar1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 212, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 212, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 213, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 191, 63))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 113, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.progressBar1.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Franklin Gothic Medium")
        self.progressBar1.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar1.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.progressBar1.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.progressBar1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.progressBar1.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.progressBar1.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.progressBar1.setAccessibleName("")
        self.progressBar1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127); border-radius: 10px")
        self.progressBar1.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar1.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar1.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar1.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.progressBar1.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.BottomToTop)
        self.progressBar1.setObjectName("progressBar1")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 90, 491, 301))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 50px")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setLineWidth(0)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 211, 51))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setIndent(85)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 131, 51))
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 25px")
        self.btn1.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn1.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btn1.setDefault(False)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.progressBar1.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 795, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.progressBar1.setFormat(_translate("MainWindow", "%p%"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Клик"))
        self.btn1.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Backspace"))


"""сам нейрон"""
class Neuron(QThread):
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)                              # !!!
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()                                     # !!!
    
    def __init__(self, input_data, expectedResult):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.input_data = input_data
        self.expectedResult = expectedResult
        self.iteration = 1
        
        self.weight = 0.01
        self.last_error = 1.1
        self.smoothing = 0.00001
        
    def run(self):
        """Цикл обучения нейрона"""
        while self.check_training():
            self.train(self.input_data, self.expectedResult)
            self.iteration += 1
            self.updateSignal.emit(self.iteration)                       # !!!
            self.msleep(50)          
        self.finished.emit()                                             # !!!

    def get_last_error(self):
        return self.last_error

    def get_smoothing(self):
        return self.smoothing

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.weight

    def process_input_data(self, input_data):
        return input_data * self.weight

    def train(self, input, expectedResult):
        result_now = input * self.weight

        self.last_error = expectedResult - result_now
        correction = self.last_error / result_now
        correction = correction * self.smoothing

        self.weight += correction

    def check_training(self):
        if(self.last_error > self.smoothing or self.last_error < -self.smoothing) \
            and self.iteration < 101:                                    # +++    ^
# +++       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            return True
        else:
            return False


"""Дизайн для нейрона"""
#class MyDesign(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Neuron):
class MyDesign(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDesign, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
# ???        self.ui.progressBar1
        self.ui.progressBar1.setMinimum(0)
        self.ui.progressBar1.setMaximum(100)

        """Код, что бы убрать рамки виндовса"""
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        """Кнопка"""
# ???        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(0))
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.run)

        self.input_data = 10
        self.expectedResult = 6.21
        
        self.neuron = Neuron(self.input_data, self.expectedResult) 
        self.neuron.updateSignal.connect(self.update_progressBar)           # !!! 
        self.neuron.finished.connect(self._finished)                        # !!! 

    def update_progressBar(self, value): 
        self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(value)
        
    def _finished(self): 
        self.ui.label.setText(f"weight --> <h5>{self.neuron.get_weight()}</h5>")
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()
        
        self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(0)
        self.neuron.input_data = 10
        self.neuron.expectedResult = 6.21   
        
        self.neuron.iteration = 1
        self.neuron.weight = 0.01
        self.neuron.last_error = 1.1
        self.neuron.smoothing = 0.00001
        
    def run(self):
        '''
        neuron = Neuron() 
        input_data = 10
        expectedResult = 6.21
        '''
        self.ui.label.setText("Проходит обучение нейрона")
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()
        
        self.neuron.start()

        '''
        iteration = 1
        """Цикл обучения нейрона"""
        while neuron.check_training():
            neuron.train(input_data, expectedResult)
            iteration += 1
            self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(iteration)
        print("Конец")
        print(neuron.get_weight())
        '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = MyDesign()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]